# Error with `predict.lm()` on linear model built using `caret::train()` when interaction in model

Tags: r, r-caret

**Updated on 11/9/2021**

The plot thickens a bit with this issue.  My issue is apparently a quirk of the `caret::` package.  My previous answer works for just running estimation because I can let S3 determine which variant of `predict()` to use. However, I want to calculate a 95% prediction interval for my linear model.  To do that I have to use the `predict.lm()` variant of the `predict()` function.  It works fine if I create my model using the `lm()` function, but I get the following error when I run `predict.lm()` from a model built with `caret::train()`

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  object 'Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width' not found
```

Here is a shorter reproducible example to illustrate the issue.

```
##Loading Packages and Data##
library(caret)
data(iris)

####Model with an Interaction Term####
##Building a model Using lm()##
mod.lm<-lm(Petal.Length~Petal.Width+Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width, data=iris)
print(mod.lm)#Notice the interaction term is not quoted
class(mod.lm)

##Building a model using caret::train()##
trCtrl<-trainControl(method="LOOCV", savePredictions = TRUE)
mod.caret<-train(Petal.Length~Petal.Width+Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width, data=iris, method="lm", trControl=trCtrl)
print(mod.caret$finalModel)#Notice the interaction term is now quoted
class(mod.caret$finalModel)#Notice this is also of class lm

##Getting Prediction Intervals##
PI95.lm<-predict.lm(mod.lm, iris, interval="prediction") #No Error
PI95.caret<-predict.lm(mod.caret$finalModel, iris, interval="prediction")#This will throw an error##

####Model with only additive terms Term####
##Building a model Using lm()##
mod.lm.add<-lm(Petal.Length~Petal.Width+Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width, data=iris)
print(mod.lm.add)#Notice the interaction term is not quoted
class(mod.lm.add)

##Building a model using caret::train()##
trCtrl<-trainControl(method="LOOCV", savePredictions = TRUE)
mod.caret.add<-train(Petal.Length~Petal.Width+Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width, data=iris, method="lm", trControl=trCtrl)
print(mod.caret.add$finalModel)#Notice there are now no quotes
class(mod.caret.add$finalModel)#Notice this is also of class lm

##Getting Prediction Intervals##
PI95.lm.add<-predict.lm(mod.lm.add, iris, interval="prediction") #No Error
PI95.caret.add<-predict.lm(mod.caret.add$finalModel, iris, interval="prediction")#No more error because interaction term is gone
```

**ORIGINAL POST**

I am using the `caret::` package to create and cross-validate a linear model that I then will use to predict an attribute from a rasterstack of predictor values.  In my real dataset, I need to use an interaction term and perform a power transformation.  I have replicated the issue with my fake data at the bottom.  To accomplish this, I create a linking function that I then feed to the `raster::predict()` function.  The modeling works fine.  When I run the link function on a dataframe of training data, it works fine.  However, when I run `raster:predict()`, I get the following error message

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'X3:X4' not found
```

This error message suggests that the function is attempting to find a layer in my rasterstack called `'X3:X4'` rather than creating an interaction of the variables `X3` and `X4` which are separate layers in the rasterstack.  The issue is exemplified in the reproducible example below using some fake data I created:

```
##Loading Necessary Packages##   
library(caret)#For modeling and crossvalidation
library(raster)#To handle raster data
library(snow)#For Parallel processing

set.seed(88)#For Reproducibility

##Creating some fake data for model training##
X1<-runif(100, 20, 50)
X2<-runif(100, 100, 220)
X3<-runif(100, 80, 150)
X4<-runif(100, 1000, 15000)
Y<-rnorm(100, 2000, 50)

df<-data.frame(X1=X1, X2=X2, X3=X3, X4=X4, Y=Y)

##Creating a fake model##
trCtrl<-trainControl(method="LOOCV", savePredictions = TRUE)
mod<-train(Y^0.33~X1+X2+X3*X4, data=df, method="lm", trControl=trCtrl)

##Creating rasters with fake predictor data##
WGS84<-crs("+init=epsg:4326")
RAST<-raster(xmn=-122.0, xmx=-121.5, ymn = 45.0, ymx=45.5, crs=WGS84, ncol=100, nrow=100)
R1<-RAST
values(R1)<-runif(10000, 20, 50)
R2<-RAST
values(R2)<-runif(10000, 100, 220)
R3<-RAST
values(R3)<-runif(10000, 80, 150)
R4<-RAST
values(R4)<-runif(10000, 1000, 15000)

##Combining into a single raster stack and renaming with the same predictor variable names as the training dataset##
PRED<-stack(R1, R2, R3, R4)
names(PRED)<-c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")

##Creating a linking function to undo the power transformation in the model##
linkfun<-function(mod, x){
  out<-predict(mod, x)^(1/0.33)
  return(out)
}

##Starting Parallel Processing##
beginCluster()

##Attempting to predict a new raster of the response variable from the fake model##
raster::predict(PRED, mod$finalModel, fun=linkfun, filename=paste(tempdir(), "/Example.tif", sep=""), datatype="FLT4S", format="GTiff")
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is related to raster::predict, as I also see that error when using `predict` with a `data.frame`:

```
p <- predict(mod$finalModel, data.frame(values(PRED)), fun=linkfun)
#Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'X3:X4' not found
```

And I can run your code with these values

```
library(raster)
library(caret)

## data for model training
X1 <- runif(100, 20, 50)
X2 <- runif(100, 100, 220)
X3 <- runif(100, 80, 150)
X4 <- runif(100, 1000, 15000)
Y <- rnorm(100, 2000, 50)
df <- data.frame(X1=X1, X2=X2, X3=X3, X4=X4, Y=Y)

## model
trCtrl <- trainControl(method="LOOCV", savePredictions = TRUE)
mod <- train(Y^0.33~X1+X2+X3*X4, data=df, method="lm", rControl=trCtrl)

## predictor raster data
PRED <- brick(xmn=-122.0, xmx=-121.5, ymn = 45.0, ymx=45.5, ncol=100, nrow=100, nl=4)
values(PRED) <- runif(40000, 1000, 15000)
names(PRED) <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")

linkfun <- function(mod, x){
  predict(mod, x)^(1/0.33)
}

r <- raster::predict(PRED, mod, fun=linkfun)
r
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 100, 100, 10000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 0.005, 0.005  (x, y)
#extent     : -122, -121.5, 45, 45.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      : layer 
#values     : 1.47405e-07, 2200.354  (min, max)
```

Comment: Thanks Robert.  By the way, a major tip-of-the-hat to you for the raster and terra package.  They are incredibly useful and save me hours of frustration trying to do geostatistical analyses in the clunky ESRI environment. As it turns out this was a "liveware" error.  I forgot you only need to make a call to ``mod$finalModel` if you are trying to create prediction interval.  Simply calling `mod` fixed the issue.  I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my comment to Robert, this was simply a matter of changing the model argument in `raster::predict()` from `mod$finalModel` to `mod`.  I had included the mod$finalModel because elsewhere in my workflow I create a raster of the 95% prediction interval, and the the call to `confint()` requires an `lm` object, which is generated as the `$finalModel` attribute in `caret::train()`. Below is the corrected code:

```
##Loading Necessary Packages##   
library(caret)#For modeling and crossvalidation
library(raster)#To handle raster data
library(snow)#For Parallel processing

set.seed(88)#For reproducibility

##Creating some fake data for model training##
X1<-runif(100, 20, 50)
X2<-runif(100, 100, 220)
X3<-runif(100, 80, 150)
X4<-runif(100, 1000, 15000)
Y<-rnorm(100, 2000, 50)

df<-data.frame(X1=X1, X2=X2, X3=X3, X4=X4, Y=Y)

##Creating a fake model##
trCtrl<-trainControl(method="LOOCV", savePredictions = TRUE)
mod<-train(Y^0.33~X1+X2+X3+X4+X3:X4, data=df, method="lm", trControl=trCtrl)

##Creating rasters with fake predictor data##
WGS84<-crs("+init=epsg:4326")
RAST<-raster(xmn=-122.0, xmx=-121.5, ymn = 45.0, ymx=45.5, crs=WGS84, ncol=100, nrow=100)
R1<-RAST
values(R1)<-runif(10000, 20, 50)
R2<-RAST
values(R2)<-runif(10000, 100, 220)
R3<-RAST
values(R3)<-runif(10000, 80, 150)
R4<-RAST
values(R4)<-runif(10000, 1000, 15000)

##Combining into a single raster stack and renaming with the same predictor variable names as the training dataset##
PRED<-stack(R1, R2, R3, R4)
names(PRED)<-c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")

##Creating a linking function to undo the power transformation in the model##
linkfun<-function(mod, x){
  out<-predict(mod, x)^(1/0.33)
  return(out)
}

##Starting Parallel Processing##
beginCluster()

##Attempting to predict a new raster of the response variable from the fake model##
raster::predict(PRED, mod, fun=linkfun, filename=paste(tempdir(), "/Example.tif", sep=""), datatype="FLT4S", format="GTiff")
```